# In citrix, is it possible to create virtual machines and add them to a catalog using powershell?

Tags: powershell, citrix, xendesktop

Now I´m doing it thought the citrix studio console. There´s a powershell tab and it shows a resulting powershell script of this action but I can´t reuse this script because there are some 'ids' I can´t determine how to find.

I´m using XenDesktop 7.5

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you are looking for is new-brokermachine, ref: http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/citrix-broker-admin-v2-xd75/new-brokermachine-xd75.html.  I suppose that if you inspected the PowerShell that is executing in the PowerShell window in Citrix Studio you would see where the ids are set further up in the PowerShell execution too.